# 'float' object is not iterable, Iteration over 2 float lists

Tags: python, syntax

When I'm trying to execute this simple loop:

```
list1 = [1.5,2.6,3.9,4.0]
list2 = [3.2,4.5,5.0,5.0]
for i,j in zip(list1, list2):
 x = sum(i**2 - 2*j)
 print(x)
```

I expect the program to take evey index item in each list, iterate through the whole list and perform the arithmetical operation, and then sum the whole thing up and print the summation. for example:

```
(1.5**2 - 2*3.2) + (3.2^2 - 2*4.5) ...
```

I recieve the following error: `ValueError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Why is that? I assume it has to do with the formatting of the loop, but I still don't think that the syntax is clear to me, would appreciate help.

Comment: You mention one error in your question title, and another in the body of your question. Which error are you actually asking about?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude right, fixed it up

Comment: why add sum to (i**2 - 2 * j)

Comment: Error comes this line `sum(i**2 - 2*j)`. What exactly are trying there? For example, `sum(0.438764645)` isn't valid.

Comment: @user9594794 I expect to get the summation of all indexes

Comment: @Ch3steR Yes, My question is how to perform the arithmetics over all indexes, and then sum it up

Comment: `sum(i**2 - 2 * j for i,j in zip(list1, list2))` Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: you need to def x as an arry: `x = [] for ... x.append(i**2 - 2 * j)     (outloop) sum(x)`

Comment: @Ch3steR added a clarification of my expectation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add your lists, you can do like this:

```py
list1 = [1.5, 2.6, 3.9, 4.0]
list2 = [3.2, 4.5, 5.0, 5.0]

result = sum([a**2 - 2 * b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)])

print(result)
```

Explanations: `sum` accepts an iterable, while you give it an intermediate result of calculation. If you use `sum`, you don't need to use a loop

Comment: I tried it, and I get "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'generator' and 'float'" - is there a problem with the indexes being floats?

Comment: Have you tried with same input as given here?